# Efficiently storing data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, performance

I am trying to create a world application using jQuery (JS) and PHP. I originally tried doing this by using a MySQL database, which didn't work well - the server got overloaded with database queries and crashed.

This time I want to store the data in a text file... maybe use JSON to parse it? How would I do this? The three main things I want are:

- Name
- x-position
- y-position

The x and y positions are given from the JS. So, in order:

1. User loads page and picks username
2. User moves character, the jQuery gets the x and y position
3. The username, x and y position are sent to a PHP page in realtime using jQuery's `$.post()`
4. The PHP page has to find some way to store it efficiently without crashing the database.
5. The PHP page sends back ALL online users' names and x and y coordinates to jQuery
6. jQuery moves the character; everyone sees the animation.

Comment: So you managed to crash a MySQL server with your data, and you think using a text file instead is going to be the solution?

Comment: Would it be an option for you to buffer up your database write so you're not hitting the database as hard?

Comment: @Laurent I just thought about that. I changed my question slightly.

Comment: For something like that a NoSQL database might be best. But maybe your webserver might have to be clustered too.

Comment: BTW, why not send the subset of online users' names and x and y coordinates that is the view range.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Can you provide some metrics about your system when it crashed? E.g. number of concurrent/total users/requests, ...

Comment: It was on a shared host, that's why it crashed so early. They detected too many database queries. I think it was like 30 database queries at all once.

Comment: Then the first two questions I'd ask myself - long before considering to apply the blank iron - are a) has the mysql server (or any relational database system) been used efficiently and b) is that shared host any good (and that even only after making sure that the answer to a) is "yes").

Answer (score 4):

Storing the data in the file instead of the MySQL database isn't an option if you want to improve performance. Just because MySQL stores its data in the files too, but is use some technics to improve performance like caching and using indexes.

The fastest method to save and retrieve data on server is using RAM as a storage. Redis for example do that. It stores all the data in the RAM and can backup it to the hard drive to prevent data loss.

However I don't think the main problem here is MySQL itself. Probably you use it in an inappropriate way. But I can't say exactly since I don't know how many read and write requests your users generate, what the structure of your tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

Text files are not the best performing things on Earth. Use a key-value store like [Redis](http://redis.io/) (it has a [PHP client](https://github.com/nrk/predis/wiki)) to store them. It should be able to take a lot more beating than the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in a text file in CSV (Comma separated values) format.

For example, consider your requirements.

1,Alice,23,35
2,Bob,44,63
3,Clan,435,322

This text file can be stored and read anytime, and use `explode` function to separate values.